# Why is there such a huge price range for BNC terminators?

Tags: termination, bnc

I wanted to buy some standard BNC 50 Ohm terminators and was surprised when I saw multiple offers with prices well above 20€ per piece. I found others for around 2€ (same online shop) and now I am intrigued on why the expensive ones are more expensive. Are they in some way better? Longer lasting?

Comment: Probably tested with equipment whose calibration is traceable to a national lab, guaranteed to meet spec, and from a fully traceable supply chain. If lives depend on correct termination, that's a bargain.

Comment: Supply and demand as well. I was pricing 600 ohm terminators the other day, which are obsolete, and best I could do was $US70.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For BNC terminators there are usually the following factors that contribute to the price:

- Accuracy of the specified values (i.e. impedance is matching for the whole assembly)
- Wattage of the resistor
- Bandwidth of the whole assembly
- Linearity of attenuation of the whole assembly
- Contact quality

Some of these have similar influences to all kind of other BNC equipment too

Comment: Especially the second point (max. power dissipation)  affects price very much.

Comment: @Curd: Plus it strongly interacts with the first one. You can get two 5W terminators and after using them for ten minutes one is still good, the other garbage.

Comment: Another point is brand name and associated expected parameter spread. Very good and cheap BNC connectors do exist; however, to find out whether you found one you'd have to either spend time characterizing the damn thing or money buying an instrument that will do it for you.